# Does Python perform Bound Checking?

Tags: python, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

So, I'm reading the code on this website (Python code):

[Solution to problem: Best time to buy & sell iii (leetcode)](http://yucoding.blogspot.com/2012/12/leetcode-question-10-best-time-to-buy.html)

And I wonder why in line 19, Python didn't give any bound checking errors.

Thank you!

Comment: L19: ``ed = prices[-1]``

Comment: it seems like so far that might not be an effective way for you to learn python

Answer (score 5):

Line 19:

```
ed = prices[-1]
```

In python, a list (array) index of -1 means the last element in the list by definition. So it is not out of bounds, hence no error.

Comment: Thanks! So for line 20:  `for i in range(n-2,-1,-1):` does this mean the for loop will start from n - 2 and ends at 0 (I think -1 here represent the end of the array in backward direction). Thanks again!

Comment: @HuyenNguyen Yes, it does mean that the loop will start from n-2 and end at 0. The last argument is the step. A step of -1 means to decrement.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, python does bounds checking.  When you use a negative index in python, you are counting from the end of the array.  The line in question:

```
ed = prices[-1]
```

This is setting `ed` to the last element in `prices`.